# How can I use a custom theme for the Hyper terminal?

Tags: hyperterminal

Good evening!

I am on a linux machine using the Hyper terminal as my day-to-day terminal emulator. I have found a color scheme I really like, but unfortunately, it seems there isn't a hyper theme available that's close enough to my likings. I thought it would be simple to just use a custom theme, but I'm struggling to see whether or not it's possible.

For now, i have an `index.js` file I copied from another theme, replacing the colors with the ones i want, and a `package.json`, in a local directory, but since I'm not running a dev version of hyper, i don't see how i can use them on my machine, without publishing them. Is there a solution to this?

Thanks in advance!!